# iOS application runs on iPhone but not iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm trying to run my application on both my iPhone and iPad but whilst the application runs on the iPhone, when I run it on the iPad I get the following error:

> Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class
>   is not key value coding-compliant for the key ipad_switch_view.'

I only have the one ViewController and my iphone and ipad storyboards are the exact same. They both have a single text view and a switch which I've linked both with the same method.

Is there any reason I can't think of why this is happening? I'm still very new to iOS programming.

Comment: check your .xib file where any object has set outlet named ipad_switch_view but in .h file it is missing.

Comment: This usually happens when an Interface Builder or Storyboard connection hasn't properly been made. Sometimes you'll make a connection, and then delete the code that the connection was made to. Interface Builder still has a reference to the code, which causes the key/value compliant run time error. You can also get this error if you haven't assigned the proper class to a view controller. If you've written code for a particular view controller, be sure to set the class appropriately in Interface Builder for that View Controller.

Comment: Check out your outlets of xib and every objects included in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your IBOutlet in your xib or storyboard

For example . You can see in below image.

[image]

> In above image **lblserverDateTime** is not exist in outlet .So remove
>   that type of IBoutlet or add into your class..